# Problem in downloading videos using youtube-dl

Tags: video-streaming

How can I download videos from "https://zeroinfy.in/" using youtube-dl?  I had tried, but not succeed and searched, but I did not find a solution. In the Android app for this academy, videos are freely downloadable. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please share a link where video is there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete list of all the sites `youtube-dl` supports:

https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html

The site you want to download from is not among them.